# How to partition pands dataframe by month and year

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe which has a date field in it. I want to create sub dataframes from the dataframe by MM/YYYY. i can do this by specifying date rages but i want to make it dynamic where the whole dataframe partitioned base on month years in the date column.

From:

```
        sales              date
  0       420        01/10/2021
  1       380        01/15/2021
  3       420        01/20/2021
  4       380        02/02/2021
  5       420        03/10/2021
  6       380        03/13/2021
```

To:

```
        sales              date
  0       420        01/10/2021
  1       380        01/15/2021
  3       420        01/20/2021


        sales              date
  0       380        02/02/2021


        sales              date
  0       420        03/10/2021
  1       380        03/13/2021
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
for _, g in df.groupby([df.date.dt.year, df.date.dt.month]):
    print(g)
    print()
```

Prints:

```
   sales       date
0    420 2021-01-10
1    380 2021-01-15
3    420 2021-01-20

   sales       date
4    380 2021-02-02

   sales       date
5    420 2021-03-10
6    380 2021-03-13
```

Comment: Andrej, could you please explain what is the purpose of `_,g` in `for _,g in df.groupby([df.date.dt.year, df.date.dt.month])` construct

Comment: @KarthikS `_` in this context contains the index returned by `.groupby` (`(2021, 1)`, `(2021, 2)`, `(2021, 3)`). We don't need it, so we use the name `_` (which is common practice for not used variables). `g` contains grouped dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

Do `groupby` then save into `dict`

```
d = {x : y for x , y in df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.strftime('%y-%m'))}
d
Out[8]: 
{'21-01':    sales        date
 0    420  01/10/2021
 1    380  01/15/2021
 3    420  01/20/2021, '21-02':    sales        date
 4    380  02/02/2021, '21-03':    sales        date
 5    420  03/10/2021
 6    380  03/13/2021}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the date column into a datetime object, so that you can more easily extract the month-year data.
2. Extract the month-year data into a new column.
3. Group by this new column, to extract unique dataframes.

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
df['month/year'] = str(df['date'].dt.month) +  "/" + (df['date'].dt.year)
for month_year, df_month_year in df.groupby('month/year'):
    print(df_month_year)
```